# Intersected or Common values of different queries based on values from Another Query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, intersection

I've a parent table like this

```
    ID    |   ParentTestID    |   TestID
----------------------------------------
    1     |        10         |    15
    2     |        10         |    25
    3     |        10         |    35
```

Second Table

```
ID    |   TestID    |   TestName    |   LanguageID
-----------------------------------------
1     |   15         |    Test1      |      8  
2     |   15         |    Test2      |      3  
3     |   15         |    Test3      |      1  
4     |   25         |    Test1      |      5  
5     |   25         |    Test2      |      3  
6     |   25         |    Test3      |      4  
7     |   35         |    Test1      |      3  
8     |   35         |    Test2      |      8  
9     |   35         |    Test3      |      9
```

My scenario is to find the common language ID from the second table when I know the ParentTestID only on the first table

**That means if I know the parent TestID 10, the result will be 3** since all the testIDs under 10 having a common language ID 3

Also the number of testIDs under a parent ID is unpredictable. it wont be just 3.

Am looking for query without cursor or such complications.

Comment: by `common languageID` you mean that ID is present in all `TestID` of the same `ParentID`?

Comment: Your result is just a single count and the paremeter is @ParentTestID ?

Comment: @491243 LanguageID in for each test in the second table. The testname will varies.as an example: TestSpanish (LangID 8) , TestFrench(LangID 3), TestEnglish (LanguageID 1)
So these test names will varies

So my requirement is to find all Tests with a Common LanguageID which is 3

Comment: @TimSchmelter No.. It wont be always a single row element. it will be multiple rows if multiple common languageID there for testIDs
Yea.. Only parameter is ParentTestID

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT b.LanguageID
FROM    firstTable a
        INNER JOIN secondTable b    
            ON a.TestID = b.TestID
WHERE   a.ParentTestID = 10
GROUP   BY b.languageID
HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT b.TestID) =
        (
          SELECT COUNT(c.testid) 
          FROM   firsttable c 
          WHERE  c.parenttestid = 10
        )
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bd795/7)

In the line `HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT b.TestID)`, it is not needed to use `DISTINCT` keyword if the `LanguageID` is unique for every `TestID`.

Comment: You can simplify the query by removing the join in the subquery.

Comment: @GordonLinoff yep I can remove it but if I will remove the join in the subquery, how will I know if the `TestID` is from the specific `ParentTestID`?

Comment: You can do:  `select count(c.testid) from firsttable c where c.parenttestid = 10`.

Comment: @491243 You are Awesome. it worked fine. But any scope of simplifying it?

Comment: @sforsandeep see Gordon's comment.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Cheers mate... that was perfect

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there would be only 3 `tests` for each `parenttestid`, you may try the following query:

```
select distinct languageid
from child
where testid in (select testid from parent where parenttestid = 10)
group by languageid having count(*) > 2
```

### Edit:

If the count is not fixed, then this query would work:

```
select distinct languageid
from child
where testid in (select testid from parent where parenttestid = 10)
group by languageid
having count(testid) = (select count(testid) from parent where parenttestid = 10)
```

Comment: We cant predict anything like that. it will varies always.

Comment: @sforsandeep, please check the edit. This seems to work as per your requirement.

Comment: OK.. This will work.. But please check the one marked as answer. That is more clear instead of multiple sub queries